# Questions about the optimization in R

Tags: r, optimization, statistics

The following code was presented by our teacher in a practical lesson. I have questions about the last line of the code in the optimization step using the function `optim()` but I add the other lines to clarify the work.

```
population <- read.csv("data.csv", header=FALSE, sep=';', dec=',')
```

and the data looks like:

```
1      8.29

2      5.37

3      10.61

4      5.92

5      14.99

6      9.74

7      15.47
    .
    .
    .
```

We sample 100 elements from the population as

```
Sampled_Data <- sample(population$V1, 100)
```

then we write a function to calculate the likelihood "of the log-normal distribution" for the sampled elements as

```
MyFunc <- function(Myparameters,data){
      Firstparameter <- Myparameters[1]
      Secondparameter <- Myparameters[2] 
      n <- length(data)
      Mydistribution <- -n/2*log(2*pi*(Secondparameter^2)) - sum(log(data)) - (1/(2*Secondparameter^2))*sum((log(data)-Firstparameter)^2) 
      return(Mydistribution) 
    }
```

Finally, we use the function `optim()` to estimate the two parameters of the distribution using the likelihood maximum function

```
optimisation <- optim(c(1,1),MyFunc,data=Sampled_Data)
```

in the function `optim()`, I don't understand why he added the vector `c(1,1)` while, from the documentation, we should fill it by the initial values for the parameters? does he assume that the initial values are 1 & 1 ? if so, based on what we assume the initial values.

Also, why he added `data=Sampled_Data` whereas there is no similar thing in the documentation? From the documentation, after adding the function, we should add other things like the gradient, method and bounds! but not the data we have!

Finally, if I want to specify the lower and upper bounds, it is not clear for me which values to use in my case with the log normal distribution.

**I was lost where to post the question, here or in cross validated but I saw similar questions here. Anyway, if it is not the suitable place I will delete the question.**

Comment: Based on these phrases: "I don't understand why he [...]", "does he assume", "Also, why he added [...]"; it appears that your instructor is male and probably the best person to answer your questions pertaining to why he did certain actions for this assignment.

Comment: @JohnH unfortunately he is abroad and we can't contact or reach him!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unnamed arguments to functions in R are assigned in the order that they appear in the definition.

If we look at help with `help(optim)`:

```
Usage
optim(par, fn, gr = NULL, ...,
      method = c("Nelder-Mead", "BFGS", "CG", "L-BFGS-B", "SANN",
                 "Brent"),
      lower = -Inf, upper = Inf,
      control = list(), hessian = FALSE)
```

We will see that the first argument by default is `par`. Therefore, you are correct that your instructor has set `par = c(1,1)` and `fn = MyFun`. You will see also in `help(optim)` that you can set `upper =` and `lower =` arguments as well.

If you look back to the definition of `MyFun`, you will see that the first argument is `Myparameters`. Therefore, when `optim` is called, `c(1,1)` is passed to `MyFun` as its first argument. Thus, on the initial step, both `Firstparameter` and `Secondparameter` will be set to `1`.

Finally, if you look carefully at `help(optim)`:

```
Usage
optim(par, fn, gr = NULL, ...,
      method = c("Nelder-Mead", "BFGS", "CG", "L-BFGS-B", "SANN",
                 "Brent"),
      lower = -Inf, upper = Inf,
      control = list(), hessian = FALSE)

Arguments
par Initial values for the parameters to be optimized over.

fn  A function to be minimized (or maximized), with first argument the vector of parameters over which minimization is to take place. It should return a scalar result.

gr  A function to return the gradient for the "BFGS", "CG" and "L-BFGS-B" methods. If it is NULL, a finite-difference approximation will be used.

... Further arguments to be passed to fn and gr.
```

You will see that `...` can be further arguments to be passed to `fn` and thus to `MyFun`. In this case, `data=Sampled_Data`.

Comment: and for the second question? why he added `data=Sampled_Data` after the function?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts. So we need to add `data=...` because it has a mathematical effect in the optimization process OR because the function `MyFun` contains two arguments and so when we need to pass them to correctly define the function in the optimization process. Additionally for the values of the parameters in the initial step, always we define them randomly or depending on mathematical work?

Comment: You need `data=Sampled_Data` because you are calling `MyFun` which has and uses an argument `data=` that has no default.